# using a stack to get the height of a BST

Tags: c++, stack, binary-search-tree

I am trying to get the height of a BST using a stack.  I was told that I should use preorder and measure find the largest size of the stack.  However, this does not seem to work.  Any ideas of what I am doing wrong.

```
int PBT::maxDepth() {
if (!root) {
    return -1;
}
int depth=0;
stack<TreeNode *>s;
TreeNode * nodePtr=root;
for (; ; ) {        
    while (nodePtr) {
        s.push(nodePtr);
        if (s.size() > depth)
            depth = s.size();
        nodePtr=nodePtr->left;
    }if (s.empty()) {
        break;
    }
    nodePtr=s.top();
    s.pop();
    nodePtr=nodePtr->right;
}
return depth;
```

}

Comment: If I were you, I'd find a simple test case that doesn't work and step through the code in the debugger to see whether what's happening is what you think should be happening.

Comment: I have tried multiple cases to see if there is a problem with the preorder.  I know the preorder works.

Comment: So in what way is your code not working? Can you give an example of a simple tree where it doesn't work, as well as the actual vs expected outputs?

Comment: The Depth of the tree is incorrect.  I am having trouble figuring out the calculation to get the correct height.

Answer (score 1):

The stack size is incorrect value of depth for some nodes. Eg. if the current node is a right child of other node, the stack doesn't contain this other node (our parent). For the rightest node in the tree, the stack will have no items.

You'll have to calculate the depth correctly. In your case, you may go up more levels in one pop, so subtracting one won't work, but if you save your current depth to the stack (and restore it while popping), it will work.

To do that, you should change your stack definition to eg.

```
stack<pair<TreeNode*, unsigned> > stack;
```

and add a variable `current_depth`.

For each "`nodePtr=nodeptr->left/right`", you increment `current_depth`. Push with

```
s.push(make_pair(nodeptr, current_depth));
```

and before you pop, restore `current_depth` with

```
current_depth = s.top().second;
```

(The node pointer is obviously in `.first`)

Comment: `depth` is the maximum depth found so far. Resetting it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I tried that I am still having the problem of it not adding to the variable for the right child before it pops a value of the stack

Comment: That's because you immediately go down. Anyway, it seems there isn't any miraculously simple solution, so you should do it the right way.

Comment: Can you explain that a little more.